# Simple C++ program crashes once using node pointers

Tags: c++, memory

So I never actually learned graph theory but I had seen some examples so I want to try something myself. I made a simple program which looks like this:

```
struct node
{
   node* prev;
   node* next;
   int num = 0;
   /*node()
   {
      prev = new node();
      next = new node();
   }*/
};

int main()
{
   node* curr = new node();
   curr->num = 1;
   curr->prev = curr;
   curr = curr->next;
   curr->num = 2;

   return 0;
}
```

When I uncomment the constructor it crashes on the first line of main(). When it's commented out it crashes the "curr->num = 2;" line. I don't actually know why that happens and would like to find out. Thanks!

Comment: What does next point to if you don't tell it to point to anything?

Comment: What did you think was going to happen here: `curr = curr->next;`?

Comment: The members `prev` and `next` are not initialized. `cur = cur->next` assigns an uninitialized value to `cur`. I'm not sure what you expected it to contain that would result in the following `curr->num` to do anything meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is as mentioned by UKMonkey.

The second one would be

```
   curr = curr->next;
   curr->num = 2;
```

You dont allocate memory to the next after you move to `curr->next` so you cant assign a value to a location which hasn't been initialised.

Comment: Aha. I see. So is there like a quick way to initialise them automatically or is that too complicated?

Comment: when you move your pointer to next, do another `curr = new node()` and then `curr->num=2`, provided you fixed the earlier problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
node()
{
    prev = new node();
    next = new node();
}
```

On creation of a new node, you create 2 more nodes.  This process never stops, its a recursive ctor.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the program crash at the `cum->num = 2` because you have set curr to `curr->next` that is NULL.

If you uncomment the ctor the program will crash again because you are creating an infinite cycle of initializations. Look at the stacktrace:

[image]

I can suggest a working example:

```
struct node
{
    node* prev;
    node* next;
    int num = 0;
};

int main()
{
    node* curr;

    // Make a root node:
    node* root = new node();
    root->num = 1;
    // Create a child node
    root->next = new node();

    // Set '2' at the child node
    curr = root->next;
    curr->num = 2;
    // Create a child of the child node
    curr->next = new node();

    // Set '3' at the child node of the child node
    curr = curr->next;
    curr->num = 3;

    // Etc...

    return 0;
}
```

Debug it to understand better:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! I've looked through and I seem to understand where the problem is. Now talking about the previous node, would I have to set up some sort of a temporary node which I'd set it to the current node and later on initialise the previous node with after I moving curr pointer to next?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand properly, but...
You can use pointers to operate on your nodes. 

'curr' pointer is currently at the third level child node. Look at the line: 19 and 25!
But the whole nodes structure has his root to the 'root' node.

'curr' is just a utility pointer. You can set that pointer to any node of your structure.